# php Imagick::levelImage usage

Tags: php, imagick

I have trying hard, but can't make this method works properly. 
The usage format is

```
Imagick::levelImage ( float $blackPoint , float $gamma , float $whitePoint [, int $channel = Imagick::CHANNEL_ALL ] );
```

I try use it like

```
$img->levelImage (0, 1.0, 255);
```

and

```
$img->levelImage (255, 1.0, 0);
```

or even like

```
$img->levelImage (-0.5, 1.0, 5.6);
```

but without any success.
Output image is either almost black or almost white.
All other imagick methods I use work fine, but this one is just a back-breaker for me))
I can't find any examples of usage this imagick method on the net so need help!
Maybe somebody have an good working example, help me please:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the ImageMagick documentation for [LevelImage](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/api/enhance.html#LevelImage):

> Specify the levels where the black and
>   white points have the range of
>   0-QuantumRange, and gamma has the
>   range 0-10

So a sensible call from PHP *might* look like this:

```
//bool Imagick::levelImage ( float $blackPoint , float $gamma , float $whitePoint [, int $channel = Imagick::CHANNEL_ALL ] )
$img->levelImage (20, 5, 220);
```

I'm guessing the QuantumRange is set at 255, if not, try calling [Imagick::getQuantumRange](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-getquantumrange.php) to find out what it is.

If it still doesn't seem to work, I'll figure out what's wrong by writing example code.