# Photoshop's RGB levels with ImageMagick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, photoshop

I'm attempting to convert some effects created in Photoshop into code for use with php/imagemagick. Right now I'm specifically interested in how to recreate Photoshop's RGB levels feature. I'm not really familiar with the Photoshop interface, but this is the info that I am given:

```
RGB Level Adjust
  Input levels: Shadow 0, Midtone 0.92, Highlight 255
  Output levels: Shadow 0, Highlight 255
```

What exaclty are the input levels vs. the output levels? How would I translate this into ImageMagick? Below you can see what I have tried, but it does not correctly render the desired effect (converting Photoshop's 0-255 scale to 0-65535):

```
$im->levelImage(0, 0.92, 65535);
$im->levelImage(0, 1, 65535);
```

This was mostly a stab in the dark since the parameter names don't line up and for output levels the number of parameters don't even match. Basically I don't understand exactly what is going on when photoshop applies the adjustment. I think that's my biggest hurdle right now. Once I get that, I'll need to find corresponding effects in ImageMagick.

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on in Photoshop and how to replicate that with ImageMagick?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539307/php-imagicklevelimage-usage

Comment: I'm not sure he wants clarification on the usage of the API as much as he wants to understand how to reproduce the Photoshop effect using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I stumbled across this website: http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/levels/index.php

Based on the information there, I was able to come up with the following php which seems pretty effective at simulating what Photoshop does with input and output and all that.

```
function levels($im, $inshadow, $midtone, $inhighlight, $outshadow, $outhighlight, $channel = self::CHANNEL_ALL) {
    $im->levelImage($inshadow, $midtone, $inhighlight, $channel);
    $im->levelImage(-$outshadow, 1.0, 255 + (255 - $outhighlight), $channel);
}
```

This assumes that the parameters to levelImage for blackpoint and whitepoint are on a scale of 0-255. They might actually be 0-65535 on your system. If that's they can it's easy enough to adjust it. You can also check what value your setup uses with $im->getQuantumRange(). It will return an array with a string version and a long version of the quantum. From there it should be easy enough to normalize the values or just use the new range.

Comment: any way to implement this in GD?

Comment: Would you have a complete working example? Or how the code is applied to the image? This is something I'm needing.

Comment: $im is an IMagick object (an image should have been previously loaded into that). Just apply the code you see above to your IMagick image.

Comment: Can anyone explain how the -$outshadow value is valid? I understand the input values for levelImage should be between 0-255, what happens with a negative value? Also wont the outhighlight value of (255 + (255 - $outhighlight)) always be 255 or higher? Once again I thought levelImage wants a value between 0-255?

Answer (score 3):

Shadows, Midtones and Highlights are colors that fall within a certain range of luminosity. For example, shadows are the lower range of the luminosity histogram, midtones are colors in the middle and highlights are the ones up high. However - you can't use a hard limit on these values, which is why you will have to use curves like these that weight the histogram (a pixel may lie in multiple ranges at the same time).

[image: Shadows, MidTones and Highlights]

To adjust shadows, midtones and highlights separately, you will need to create a weighted sum per pixel that uses the current shadow, midtone and highlight values to create a resultant value.

I don't think you can do this directly using ImageMagick API's - perhaps you could simply write it as a filter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As far as I understand, shadows and highlights are parabolas, right? But what would be a formula of it?

Comment: @MaksimSorokin No - they gaussians (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) appropriately scaled and translated.

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.levelimage.php): The first value is the black point (shadow) input value, the middle is a gamma (which I'm guessing is the same as Photoshop's midpoint), and the last is the white point (highlight) input value.

The output values are fixed at the quantum values of the image type, there's no need to specify them.

Comment: see, but that's more or less what I have tried and it does not produce the same results as the same in Photoshop

Comment: @greggory.hz, "does not produce the same results" is not very descriptive. Help us help you.

Comment: You're right, that's not very descriptive. But that was intentional since I'm hoping for a one-to-one mapping from photoshop to image magick. I suspect that's not likely. So if lieu of that, I'd be thrilled with resources to understand how photoshop's rgb levels work so I can get the low-level knowledge to tweak properly (rather than just aimlessly) to achieve the results I want.

Comment: @greggory.hz See my answer above, it aims to do exactly that.

Comment: @greggory.hz, I don't use either Photoshop or ImageMagick but I know enough about the fundamentals to provide a correct answer if I wasn't working blind. Based on the information I have, either `$im->levelImage(0, 0.92, 65535);` or `$im->levelImage(0, 0.92, 255);` should be exactly equivalent to Photoshop. If it isn't, please tell me how far off it is.

Comment: @greggory.hz, the midtone is definitely a gamma value, but it might be inverted. Try using 1.0/0.92 and see if it matches.

Comment: You are correct, it does seem to be the gamma value, but I don't think it's inverted. But I've supplied the ultimate solution I came to in another answer. And I apologize that I can't quantify effectively how far "off" the results were, but they were just wrong. They don't take into account the output values it seems.