# Manipulate Javascript image shadow, midtone and highlight image levels (Photoshop feature)

Tags: javascript, image, imagemagick, photoshop

I was wondering if it is possible to create a Javascript (browser, not Node.js) script able to manipulate the shadow, midtone and highlight image levels of an image. This feature is available in image editors as Photoshop (see below).

[image: wanted]

I have found https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp and this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707738/photoshops-rgb-levels-with-imagemagick) but I can't figure it out.

My last hope is to run it on a server with Node.js and bindings to imagemagick, but running it for free on a browser is much better.

Comment: You should remove the "node.js" tag if you don't want answers about node.js

Comment: Node.js tag removed

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```js
var values = {
  hshadow: 0,
  vshadow: 0,
  blur: 0,
  spread: 0,
  color: '#000'
};

$('[name="hshadow"]').on('change', function() {
  values.hshadow = $(this).val() + 'px';
  
  $('.box').css('box-shadow', Object.values(values).join(' ') );
});

$('[name="vshadow"]').on('change', function() {
  values.vshadow = $(this).val() + 'px';
  
  $('.box').css('box-shadow', Object.values(values).join(' ') );
});


$('[name="blur"]').on('change', function() {
  values.blur = $(this).val() + 'px';
  
  $('.box').css('box-shadow', Object.values(values).join(' ') );
});

$('[name="spread"]').on('change', function() {
  values.spread = $(this).val() + 'px';
  
  $('.box').css('box-shadow', Object.values(values).join(' ') );
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<input type="range" name="hshadow" min="-50" max="50">
<input type="range" name="vshadow" min="-50" max="50">
<input type="range" name="blur" min="-50" max="50">
<input type="range" name="spread" min="-50" max="50">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can control the levels with the following scriptlistner code:

```
// usage
change_levels(21, 0.5, 255)


function change_levels(num1, num2, num3)
{
  // num1 integer 0 - 255
  // num2 double 0.0 - 1.0
  // num3 integer 0 - 255

  // =======================================================
  var id487 = charIDToTypeID( "Lvls" );
  var desc108 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id488 = charIDToTypeID( "Adjs" );
  var list19 = new ActionList();
  var desc109 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id489 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
  var ref72 = new ActionReference();
  var id490 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
  var id491 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
  var id492 = charIDToTypeID( "Cmps" );
  ref72.putEnumerated( id490, id491, id492 );
  desc109.putReference( id489, ref72 );
  var id493 = charIDToTypeID( "Inpt" );
  var list20 = new ActionList();
  list20.putInteger( num1 ); // num 1
  list20.putInteger( num3 ); // num 3
  desc109.putList( id493, list20 );
  var id494 = charIDToTypeID( "Gmm " );
  desc109.putDouble( id494, num2 ); //num 2
  var id495 = charIDToTypeID( "LvlA" );
  list19.putObject( id495, desc109 );
  desc108.putList( id488, list19 );
  executeAction( id487, desc108, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

Word of warning: you may have to adjust the gamma value (the input maybe between 0 and 1 as it hasn't been adjusted from the Photoshop values of 9.99 and 0.10) But you should be able to add that into the function.

Answer (score -1):

Using Imagemagick you can do

```
convert image -level bp,wp,gamma result
```

where bp is the shadow (black point) value, wp is the highlight (white point) value and gamma is the midpoint value. Note that the bp and wp values should be in the Quantumrange of your ImageMagick compile, e.g. for Q16, values range from 0 to 65535. For Q8, values range from 0 to 255. However, you can use percent values for bp and wp, which I find much easier. The gamma value is a float >0 where a value of 1 is no change. see http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#level

Comment: Please explain how you run the `convert` command in the browser as stated in the question.

Comment: You cannot use the ImageMagick in a browser directly. But he asked if no javascript solution, then what was the ImageMagick command. So I do not see why **@xenoid** marked this answer down. I answered the ImageMagick part of his question. Please read the question better. He asked "My last hope is to run it on a server with Node.js and bindings to imagemagick, but running it for free on a browser is much better."